# Marching Band Theme

Tags: riddle

I’m trying to figure out my marching band’s season theme. This is the clue we were given. I will know the answer on Monday so if you guess correctly or close, I will make sure to mark it. I hope you guys can help me think of a possible answer until then. Here it is:

I can't see you but am full of you. Somebody fools me but nobody fools me. Who am I?

Comment: So this is an ongoing contest or competition, whose answer you don't know, and for which you are asking help?

Comment: @WeatherVane "Contest or competition" implies some sort of reward for winning, this sounds like just a friendly challenge.

Comment: I'm guessing this is more teaser than actual solvable riddle - something designed to spur speculation, and which when you know the answer you can see how the clue fits, but which is insufficient to allow you to forward-solve to get the answer from the clue. I guess you'll find out soon enough :)

Comment: ad knowledge tag please ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it could be a band’s season theme but maybe its:

> Ego

**line 1:**

> I can't see you but am full of you.

means:

> The ego has several meanings and if we examine it in the sense of  the "I" - the person is full of himself and self-assured but does not see himself because he is infected with the thing and can not judge himself objectively

**line 2:**

> Somebody fools me but nobody fools me

means:

> **Somebody fools me**-Sometimes the ego is interpreted as "egocentric" (the inability to distinguish between the self and the other) or egoism (the urge to maintain and improve one's own positive views in a non-positive way) and then fools the person but **nobody fools me**-In Sigmund Freud's structural model of the mind, the ego is the organized part, the realist, mediating between the desires of the id and the Supreme Self, it acts according to the principle of reality and therefore difficult to deceive it.

By the way, congratulations for joining the site, welcome!